# Concatenate variable to itself in Ansible

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I am trying to concatenate variable to itself in an Ansible playback loop, but I am unable to do it. Might be its simple but unable to achieve this.

What I am trying here.

```
- name: all directories
  set_fact: all_dir={{ item }}
  with_items:
    - src/main/java
    - src/main/test
    - src/main/resources

- debug: var=all_dir
```

Expected Output in all_dir

```
 src/main/java src/main/test src/main/resources
```

I tried [join](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#join) . Any suggestion?

Comment: You wasn't able to use this with `join` because you are simple setting three facts instead of creating a joined variable. Do this kind of work on `vars` like @udondan answered

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have these task in my role playbook. and I am taking directories dynamically from a file. So I couldn't write in `vars`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`join` is what you should be using.

```
 - hosts: 127.0.0.1
   connection: local
   vars:
     dirs:
       - src/main/java
       - src/main/test
       - src/main/resources
     all_dir: "{{ dirs | join(' ') }}"
   tasks:
     - debug: var=all_dir
```

Or via `set_fact`:

```
 - hosts: 127.0.0.1
   connection: local
   vars:
     dirs:
       - src/main/java
       - src/main/test
       - src/main/resources
   tasks:
     - set_fact:
         all_dir: "{{ dirs | join(' ') }}"
     - debug: var=all_dir
```

---

```
TASK: [debug var=all_dir] ***************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        "all_dir": "src/main/java src/main/test src/main/resources"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solutions looks relevant to me. But I am using these task in my role playbook and I am getting dir dynamically in this playbook. So Is there any way to do this through `set_fact`?

Comment: You can use `set_fact` too. I added an alternative example above.